# Is Camel Testcontainers deprecated? What replaces it?

Tags: apache-camel

The Camel testing with Testcontainers [page](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.14.x/others/testcontainers.html) directs one to declare a test class to extend `ContainerAwareTestSupport`. I did that but the compiler is warning that ContainerAwareTestSupport is deprecated (this is Camel version 3.14.1).

What replaces this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [these](https://www.mail-archive.com/dev@camel.apache.org/msg51930.html) mails the plan is to encourage users to move on to [test-infra modules](https://github.com/apache/camel/tree/camel-3.15.0/test-infra).

Related blog post: [Good bye Camel-Testcontainers! Hello Camel's test-infra](https://camel.apache.org/blog/2022/02/camel-test-infra)

Comment: Thank you. I saw those but never saw a public "deprecated" announcement or any docs for how to use test-infra so wasn't sure. Will check into it further.

Comment: My guess is that it's still work in progress.  Documentation and tutorials are quite dated for many Apache projects and while Camel is probably among the most popular ones there's a lot to document.

Comment: New blog on this subject: https://camel.apache.org/blog/2022/02/camel-test-infra/